# Is there a way to modify a Message in the MessageQueue without removing it?

Tags: msmq

Is there a way to modify a Message in the MessageQueue without removing it?

IDEA here is that an App (app1) sends a message to MSMQ, which APP (app2) listens to MSMQ
and retrieves the message. app2 has to update the data (Message.Body) which will is used
for future reference. Finally app3 will remove it after message is processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid the answer is NO. Messaging provider are not built for this scenario. The only way to "update" a message is to retrieve that message, modify it and put it back again. But note that updated message is another message altogether, not same as the one put by first application.